# How to add ^M to end of command in a macro on gvim for windows

Tags: vim, macros

Sample macro `reg a :s/a/b/^M:s/c/d/^M`
The ^M's are valid.

I'm trying to save that to my _gvimrc file Which technically works but the ^M's are invalid.

```
let @a = ':s/a/b/^M:s/c/d/^M'
```

When I run it I get "Trailing Characters" error.

I've tried various things like \r, \n, and \r\n.

So the question is, is there some way to get a newline into my saved macro?

I should also add that if there is a better way to go about this that does not involve macros I'm open to suggestions. I have 3 or 4 find and replace commands that I want to run against my log files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<cr>` instead. And possibly `<bar>` the the one in between the two calls -- I never remember.

Otherwise, You could also have defined a command (`:h :command`)

```
" <bar> or <cr> ? i.e: untested
:command! -nargs=0 -range=1 MySub :s/a/b/<bar>:s/c/d/
```

Comment: Thanks, no luck with those either. I ended up using a script file which is probably good enough for now.  `gvim.exe" -s cmds.txt mylogfile.log`  cmds.txt   `:1,$ s/a/b/g`  one line for each command and a newline at the end to execute the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Both literal ^M as well as double-quoted, escaped `\<CR>` should work just fine:

```
let @a = 's/a/b/^M:s/c/d/^M'
let @b = "s/a/b/\<CR>:s/c/d/\<CR>"
```